# Given $f(t)$ differentiable. let $u(x,y) = yf(\cos(x-y))$. find $u'_x, u'_y$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've never seen a question like this and I'll be happy if you can help me solve it.

This is the WHOLE question: (in case it looks wierd)

> Given function $f(t)$ differentiable in every point in the plain.
>
> Let $u(x, y) = yf(\cos(x - y))$.
>
> find and simplify: $u_x' + u_y'$.

In order to find $u'_x, u'_y$ I need to differentiate $f$.

What is the trick behind this question? how can I find these partial derivatives?

Comment: What is $u'_x$?

Comment: @Shuchang This is my question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you name the variable $\cos (x-y)=z \;$ and then use the chain rule as much as you need to. $u_x=y\cdot f_x=y \cdot f' \frac{\partial cos(x-y)}{\partial x}=-yf'sin(x-y)\cdot 1$ Where $f'$ is differentiation with respect to the variable $\cos (x-y)$. Thus $u_x+u_y=-yf'\sin(x-y)+[f-yf'\sin(x-y) \cdot(-1)]=f.$

Comment: Its harder to understand the question then solve it .. XD. thank you!